# Setting autoscaling to automatic (preview) for a resource in Azure on bicep

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, azure-app-service-plans, azure-autoscaling-block

I need to set the autoscaling for a resource to automatic (the option which is currently in preview). I can do it through the portal but couldn't find any documentation to do it in a bicep file.
Is it even possible, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/serverfarms?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#appserviceplanproperties), you have these two properties to configure automatic autoscaling:

```
resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2022-03-01' = {
  name: appServicePlanName
  location: location
  sku: {
    // Need to be Premium V2 or V3
  }
  properties: {
    elasticScaleEnabled: true
    maximumElasticWorkerCount: 30
  }
}
```